# The grammar of "one another"

Tags: grammar, nouns, pronouns, syntactic-analysis, determiners

In sentences such as:

- They talked to one another

Is the string *one another* a constituent, or are the two words part of a mandatorily gapped coordination of preposition phrases (or even verb phrases)?

If they are a constituent, are they an asyndetic coordination?

If they are not a coordination, is this a headed phrase? In which case which word is the head here, and which the complement?

Comment: _One another_ is a version of the reciprocal _each other_, and they should be investigated together. I would say both are constituents, though they are both separable, and they play strange games with coreference restrictions. (For instance, how does the reflexive refer in _Each man considers the other to be superior to himself_?) I'd also say they are conjunctive -- _dvandva_ compounds that function as reciprocal pronouns. As to headedness, this is a matter between you and your confessor; me, I think _head_ is a very loose term that adds nothing to formal descriptions.

Comment: For other readers: [A dvandva  (Sanskrit: dvandva "pair") is a linguistic compound in which multiple individual nouns are concatenated to form an agglomerated compound word in which the conjunction 'and' has been elided to form a new word with a distinct semantic field. So, for instance, the individual words 'brother' and 'sister' may be agglomerated to 'brothersister' to express "siblings". ... The term dvandva was borrowed from Sanskrit, a language in which these linguistic compounds are common.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvandva)

Comment: This question might be better served in the Linguistic SE site.

Comment: @user240918 This is meant to be a site for linguists! ;) Linguistics SE doesn't accept questions about specific languages, so it would just get re-routed here ...

Answer (score 1):

**(1) *One another* is not a syntactically complex phrase**

The reciprocal *one another* is not well described as a case of asyndetic coordination because you cannot paraphrase its meaning as 'one AND another', as shown in (1).

> (1) *They talked to one another* ≠ *They talked to one and another*.

Furthermore, *one another* is not correctly described as a complex syntactic phrase with a head and a complement either. The reason is that complement selection is productive whereas *one another* is a fixed expression, as shown in (2) and (3).

> (2) *one* does not freely select a complement
>   a. They like one another.
>   b. *They like one other.
>   c. *They like one the other.
>   d. *They like one all.
>   etc.

> (3) *another* does not freely select a complement
>   a. They like one another.
>   b. *They like all another.
>   c. *They like each another.
>   d. *They like themselves another.
>   etc.

It follows that *one another* should be analyzed as **neither a case of asyndetic coordination nor a complex headed syntactic phrase with a head and a complement**. Rather, the expression should be described as a third category.

**(2) What we know about *one another***

We can list the following points about *one another*:

First, it distributes like any other nominal phrase. For instances, it can take possessive *'s* like other nominal phrases, as shown in (4). It can also be coordinated with another nominal phrase, as in (5). The item is therefore pronominal in nature. For syntactic purposes it behaves like a single word, or a single pronoun, replacing a noun phrase.

> (4)  They try to understand **[one another]'s** culture
>   (cf. [John]'s culture, [The Queen of England]'s culture)
>
> (5) They love [the new Star Wars movie] and [one another].

Second, the internal structure of *one another* is likely [one [another]], with *another* more deeply embedded than *one*, rather than [[one] another], with *one* more deeply embedded that *another*. That's because the historical ancestor of the structure had the corresponding hierarchy. This is illustrated by historical examples where *one* and *another* were split by the main verb, as in (6). Hence, [one [ ... [another]]] likely developed into [one [another]].

> (6) they will [one] **helpe** [another] as brethren
>   <sub>Aggas, Edward (1588) *The politicke and militarie discourses of the Lord de La Nouue*</sub>

Third, there is no evidence that the modern form *one another* is a headed compound, as neither *one* nor *another* function as the semantic head of a compound. Hence, it not only functions as a single word from the perspective of syntax, but word-internally it also seems to be headless.

> (7) one another ≠ a kind of *another* ≠ a kind of *one*
>   (cf. *Orange juice* = a kind of "juice")

Fourth and finally, the reason why there is no obvious head is likely that the historical ancestor involved a verb as the head of both *one* and *another*. Since the head was external to both items, the modern successor did not inherit an obvious head either.